# Agile Toolkit unable to find showMessage() for DVD rental example

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I'm working through the Agile Toolkit DVD rental example. In the "Day3 - Creating Administrator's Interface" part of the tutorial, it adds the administrator interface and provides the ability to add a users email and password to the database.

In the "Customers" tab, I click on the "Set Password" button for an existing customer and a pop-up appears to allow entry of the password. I enter a password and click OK or Cancel. Using Firebug, there is an error message that is meant to appear using the showMessage() function:

```
showMessage is not defined
(?)(ret=undefined)1 (line 440)
success(res="<h2>BaseException</h2>\n...d></tr>\n</table></div>\n")start-atk4.js (line 183)
d(d=Object { url="/agiletoolkit/admin/?pa...d_set_password=1&value=", isLocal=false, global=true, more...}, f=["<h2>BaseException</h2>\n...d></tr>\n</table></div>\n", "success", Object { readyState=4, responseText="<h2>BaseException</h2>\n...d></tr>\n</table></div>\n", status=200, more...}])jquery....min.js (line 16)
d(a=200, c="success", l=Object { text="<h2>BaseException</h2>\n...d></tr>\n</table></div>\n"}, n="Date: Tue, 06 Mar 2012 ...xt/html; charset=utf-8\n")jquery....min.js (line 16)
d(e=readystatechange , i=undefined)jquery....min.js (line 16)
[Break On This Error]   

showMessage("Error in AJAXec response: "+e+"\n"+response_text);
```

Where is showMessage() defined? I searched the atk4 source, but nothing showed up.

I logged into mysql and checked the "customer" table and it is not being updated with the password. Once I've fixed the showMessage() error, I'll track down why the table is not being updating. Maybe I have not setup something correctly.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable pop-ups and make sure all javascript files are loaded. Don't worry about the "error in ajaxer response", but rather than the nature of the BaseException which came back inside the response instead of javascript code.

Comment: Thanks, I added an exception to Firefox's pop-up blocker and the pop-up with the complete error appeared. Strange, normally firefox notifies me that there is a pop-up request....

The error was due to a type-o in mgr.php, thanks.